# unregisterDevice function of the ibm-mfp-push cordova plugin not working with iOS 10 / XCode 8

Tags: push-notification, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobile-services

I am currently developing an Ionic/Cordova app and using the cordova plugin **ibm-mfp-push** to manage push notifications.
The plugin is working fine with Android. But I am facing some problems with the iOS implementation.

When trying to use the unregisterDevice function of the CDVMFPPush swift class, I get the following error:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

The app crashes at the following line:

`self.push.unregisterDevice({ (response:IMFResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in`

Seems like self.push is nil.

Could it be a side effect due to the migration to iOS 10 / XCode 8?
Could you please help me to sort this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XCode 8 is not yet supported. The SDK teams are working on updating the libraries, so hopefully this will be available soon.

---

**UPDATE:**

The new libraries have been released, so Xcode 8 is now works correctly.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the info. Would you have any update on this please? Any estimate release date?

Comment: You can track the status of the Cordova plugin by taking a look at the development branch here: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-core/tree/development

Comment: After the core plugin is complete (linked above), work will be done to complete the Push plugin.

Comment: The new core/push plugin is now complete and works on Xcode 8.